# OnClickListeners for Recyclerviews -Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I have tried to look out for an answer to the behavior of my views but I seem not find any question or solution related to it. My recycler views seemed to be set up well. I just realized that my app is not responding in the right way to the OnClickListeners.

I have set up toasts in my adapter for the recycler view click events. When i have 10 views. When i click on a view, it gives a text of another view. It seems it randomly gives me the text of another view amongst the 9 remaining views.  What could be the cause of this?

**Activity**

```
protected  override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.content_frame);
            LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, content);

            setUpRecyclerView();

        }

public void setUpRecyclerView(){

            rv = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            layoutManager.Orientation = LinearLayoutManager.Vertical;
            layoutManager.ReverseLayout = true;
            layoutManager.StackFromEnd = true;
            rv.HasFixedSize = true;
            rv.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            }
```

**Adapter**

```
    public class FeedViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, View.IOnClickListener, View.IOnLongClickListener

        {

            public FeedViewHolder(View itemView):base(itemView)
            {
              //binding of variables here


                itemView.SetOnClickListener(this);
                itemView.SetOnLongClickListener(this);



            }

            public void OnClick(View v)
            {
                itemClickListener.OnClick(v, AdapterPosition, false);
            }

            public bool OnLongClick(View v)
            {
                itemClickListener.OnClick(v, AdapterPosition, true);
                return true;
            }

            public class FeedAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, ItemClickListener

            {


                public FeedAdapter(RssObject rssObject, Context mContext)
                {

                    this.mContext = mContext;
                    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.From(mContext);
                    activity = (MainActivity)mContext;

                }




                public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
                {
                     hold = holder as FeedViewHolder;
//binding 
                     hold.itemClickListener = this;


                }


                public void OnClick(View view, int position, bool isLongClick)
                {

                    Toast.MakeText(activity, "Main text : " + hold.txtContent.Text, ToastLength.Long).Show();

                }




            public override int ItemCount
            {

                get { return rssObject.items.Count; }

            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Could this be caused by the layout of my recyclerview please?

Comment: you have `int position`, why dont you use it?

Comment: @pskink  yes i do use int position in binder like this `hold.txtContent.Text = rssObject.items[position].description;`

Comment: so do the same in `OnClick`: toast the value of `rssObject.items[position].description`

Comment: btw, do not use toasts for debugging purposes: use `Log.d` instead

Comment: alright..That works..thanks for the heads up too :) appreciate lot!